# In JQGrid, How can I dynamically get the column header label when validating a filtertoolbar field?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, header, label

I have a jqGrid with the filtertoolbar option enabled.  For a column or columns in the grid, I want to validate the column in some fashion, e.g., if an input field exceeds a certain length, display an alert.

When I display an alert, I want to display the column header label in colNames to a user, not the colmodel name for that input field, as that will be clearer to the user.   I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durindal/ejnrtocw/19/) example  with a simple example for the "Client Name" field.  "Client Name" is hard-coded in the alert message.  Ideally, I don't want to hard-code the label as it could change, e.g., "Client Name" could be changed to "Customer Name".  I don't want to go back into the function to change it each time.  Changing it in one place is trivial, but I may have a grid with several columns and associated functions involving the filter toolbar fields, and changing the labels across everywhere is inefficient.

I have searched the jqGrid documentation but have not found a function to do this.  I know that the column labels are enclosed in divs named as jqgh_{grid name}_{column name}, e.g., jqgh_test1_name in the jsfiddle, and I can get the div contents, but I would have to parse out the label from the rest of the content, which seems like more work than is needed.  Is there a built-in capability in jqGrid to do this, or will I have to parse the label from the div, or is there another approach that I can take?

Thanks in advance...

```
<table id="test1"></table>
.ui-widget { font-size: 0.8em }
$("#test1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client Name', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'm/d/Y', srcformat: 'Y-m-d'}},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});

$("#test1").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                autosearch: true,
                stringResult: false,
                searchOnEnter: true,
                defaultSearch: "cn",
            });

var maxNameLength = 10;
$("input[id=gs_name]").blur(function () {
    if (this.value.length > maxNameLength) {
                        alert('Client Name is longer than ' + maxNameLength + ' characters.');
                    }
});
            $('#gs_invdate').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true
            });

    var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    $("#test1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement your requirement the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejnrtocw/20/ for example use the following code for example

```
$("input[id=gs_name]").blur(function () {
    var $th = $(this).closest(".ui-search-toolbar>th"),
        colIndex = $th[0].cellIndex,
        $colHeader = $th.parent().siblings(".ui-jqgrid-labels").children("th").eq(colIndex),
        colHeaderText = $colHeader.children("div").text();
    if (this.value.length > maxNameLength) {
        alert(colHeaderText + ' is longer than ' + maxNameLength + ' characters.');
    }
});
```

where the first two lines are the mostly important. [colIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp) exists in every `<td>` and `<th>` element and gives us the position (0-based) in the patent. So `colIndex` is the column index So one can use it as the index of `colNames` parameter to access the column text:

```
$("input[id=gs_name]").blur(function () {
    var $th = $(this).closest(".ui-search-toolbar>th"),
        colIndex = $th[0].cellIndex,
        p = $("#test1").jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        colHeaderText = p.colNames[colIndex];
    if (this.value.length > maxNameLength) {
        alert(colHeaderText + ' is longer than ' + maxNameLength + ' characters.');
    }
});
```

See the next demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejnrtocw/21/